# REVTeX citations not superscripting with prb class option

Tags: citing, superscripts, revtex

In lieu of a *M*WE, my WE is [this REVTeX template and sample](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/revtex-4-dot-2-template-and-samples/yydsrzvrqrzs).

I would like to use the prb class option to get superscript citations. According to the template,

> When the prb class option is used, the \cite{#1} command displays the
>   reference's number as a superscript rather than in square brackets.

However, when I uncomment the prb class option and recompile, they remain in square brackets. See for example the output of line 228 of the code:

> (Refs.~\cite{epr,feyn54,Bire82,Berman1983,witten2001,Davies1998})

With or without the prb class option, the output is the same:

> (Refs.  [1,  2,  4–6])

It has nothing to do with the tilde, which can be replaced with a space to the same effect. Why are the citations not superscripting, and how can I fix this?

EDIT: I submitted the question to APS, which maintains REVTeX. They informed me that their standards have changed and Physical Review B now uses in-line, bracketed citations. REVTeX 4.2 (for which this template was written) is the current version, so the template just needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** put `\setcitestyle{super}` after `\begin{document}`.

---

I had a look through the class file, but I couldn't really make sense of it.

It seems that the `prb` option does nothing.
The documentation says "There is no code specific to prb."
We *should* be able to get the same effect with the `citeautoscript` option, but that didn't work either.
I'm not sure why it doesn't work, I think revtex and natbib are doing things in the wrong order.

The only thing I found that did work was putting `\setcitestyle{super}` after `\begin{document}`.
It messes up `\onlinecite`, but `\cite` works as intended.

Comment: Thank you! I also submitted the question to APS, which maintains REVTeX. As it turns out, the standards have changed and Physical Review B now uses in-line, bracketed citations. I will add an edit to my question.